# React deploying as blank screen, in locally works fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx

my react app git repo link = "https://github.com/MuhdSHiBiLi/employee-front.git"
this is my host llink = "https://muhdshibili.github.io/employee-front/" it only gives a blank screen as output

how to solve this issue. am also added the home pages and deploy scripts on package.jsom. doesnt work
am tried to resolve by removing browser rote from app.js and add hash route, but no change still same blank screen in this

Answer (score 0):

Please deploy your react code on netlify,Render etc. React code needs a server for running it. Github only serves static files; you can only host your pure HTML, Css and JS file on github. It working fine on your local machine because your local machine work like a server after running "npm run start"